# Redis-Quartz integration

Tags: scala, redis, quartz-scheduler

I'm writing a scala application and in need to add a job scheduler.
Quartz seems like a proper choice (2.2.1) and I would like to use Redis along with it. 
I'm trying to integrate [redis-quartz](https://github.com/RedisLabs/redis-quartz) solution and having some difficulties compliing. 
It seems like the class implementing JobStore has a different signatures than its interface. 
for example the implementation of triggeredJobComplete on RedisJobStore is throwing an exception while the declaration on JobStore does not.
Am i missing some versioning issues ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[redis-quartz](https://github.com/RedisLabs/redis-quartz) currently complies with Quartz 2.2.0 .

Indeed, some method signatures have changed in the Quartz 2.2.1 JobStore interface, so they no longer are throwing a JobPersistenceException.

Using Quartz 2.2.0 should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the library in a own fork: https://github.com/pjsb/redis-quartz
Maybe my pull request will be accepted, then the changes.